# Select subjects from table

Tags: php, sql

I have a table called Grades and inside I have some columns:

```
Id  id_student  Subjects        grade 
3   1 [->]      Biology         8   
4   1 [->]      Math            4
5   1 [->]      Sports          4
6   1 [->]      Math            8
7   1 [->]      English         9
8   4 [->]      Sports          10
9   4 [->]      English         7
```

I selected everything from this table where id_student = student logged in

```
$sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM note WHERE id_elev = :id_elev");
$sth->bindParam(":id_elev", $_SESSION['id']);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

So all I selected is this:

```
Id  id_student  Subjects        grade 
3   1 [->]      Biology         8   
4   1 [->]      Math            4
5   1 [->]      Sports          4
6   1 [->]      Math            8
7   1 [->]      English         9
```

I want to make a average grade for Math , Biology , etc for this student but I want it without making a SELECT * FROM Grades WHERE $result['Subjects'] == 'Biology' because some students may not have this subject in their schedule.

I want something like this:

```
Id  id_student  Subjects        grade 
4   1 [->]      Math            4
6   1 [->]      Math            8
```

But without WHERE $results['Subjects'] == 'Math';

I'm sorry it is hard to explain when you don't know a lot of english. I hope that someone understands what I wrote and give me an advice. I can make another table called Subject if it is necessary.

Comment: Is `GROUP BY` what you are looking for? and then you could do some function on the grade column to work out the overall average like `AVG`. See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_avg.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ee5a/3

I think it does what you need. If not, it's a great place to test the query.

I used the GROUP BY function AVG() to get the average grade for each subject.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg

Here is the schema and query:

```
CREATE TABLE grades 
    (
     Id int auto_increment primary key, 
     id_student int,
     Subjects varchar(20), 
     grade int(1)
    );

INSERT INTO grades
(Id, id_student, Subjects, grade)
VALUES
('3', '1', 'Biology', 8),
('4', '1', 'Math', 4),
('5', '1', 'Sports', 4),
('6', '1', 'Math', 8),
('7', '1', 'English', 9);

SELECT id_student, Subjects, AVG(grade) FROM grades GROUP BY Subjects;
```

Comment: I can't vote up because I don't have enough reputation but this is what I need. Thank you very much Todd.

Answer (score 0):

The query below is an example of the use I mentioned in my comment

-- The AVG() function returns the average value of a numeric column.

-- because you are executing an aggregate function on the Grade column you have to specify which columns to **group** the results together **by**.

```
SELECT 
    Id
    ,Subject
    ,AVG(Grade) as 'Average Grade'     
FROM
    Result
GROUP BY
    Id
    ,Subject
```